# Macro runs only once

Tags: vba

I have a "master" timesheet macro which users open and complete. Upon close I force a macro (in ThisWorkbook) to run and rename the master to a filename held in range save name.

This works perfectly the first time the user opens Excel, edits and closes the workbook. However, if the user opens "master" timesheet the second time, completes another timesheet and closes, without closing Excel in between, then the macro does not run.

I have searched extensively to see if there is some "global variable" that I need to reset but with no joy.

Here is the code. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(SaveAsUI As Boolean)
 If Not SaveAsUI Then
    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    MSG1 = MsgBox("This File will be saved as....... " & Sheets("Timesheet").Range("savename").Value & ".xlsm", vbOKOnly, "Confirm")
    Me.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheets("Timesheet").Range("savename").Value & ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A quick question... are you sure your final Application.EnableEvents = True gets executed...  I think closing of the book, will stop the last line from executing...  May be try putting it before close...

Comment: I have moved Application.Events before ActiveWorkbook.Close as you suggest and that has resolved the mulitple running of the macro, many thanks. It has introduced a minor additional issue in that the MsgBox is now issued twice which I will look into. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Bob, seems as if this has something to do with the `BeforeClose` event. Before closing the workbook, you're trying a `SaveAs`. This could cause some issues. Did you try to debug this macro? If yes, what did you found?

Comment: Hi theghostofc, I have tried to Debug this code but cannot do so, it may be my lack of familiarity with VBA (I used to code a looong loooong time ago but have only just got into VBA). There are no error messages produced and I cannot "Step In" or run it to a break point. Having said that The King has provided a solution that moves me forward, but thank you for your suggestion.